# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

Seems like everyone has there own story when it comes to this so here is mine.

```
<%

@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock2" runat="server">
    <script runat="server">
        void AlbumSetup(object sender, RadListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            RadListViewDataItem item = (RadListViewDataItem)e.Item;
            ImageButton Imagebutton = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("AlbumImage");
            HyperLink EditAlbum = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("EditAlbum");
            HyperLink sHyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hypShareAlbum");
            HyperLink DeleteAlbums = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hypeDeleteAlbum");
            HyperLink DeleteAccess = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hypeDeleteMyAccess");
            HiddenField sharecounter = (HiddenField) e.Item.FindControl("ShareCounter");
            mygreatappz.control.Objects.Album album = item.DataItem as mygreatappz.control.Objects.Album;

            if (album != null)
            {
                if (album.AlbumDefaultImageUrl ==
                    "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-d8vnGzfqf_M/TnNs5XN0vfI/AAAAAAAAAEs/sIWhb9-7BE4/s128/no_pic302765EC-7C31-424E-AA45-FC279C6E4A66.png")
                {
                    album.AlbumDefaultImageUrl = "~/SiteImages/no_pic302765EC-7C31-424E-AA45-FC279C6E4A66 (1).png";
                }
                if (DeleteAlbums != null && album.CreatorID == PictureCrave.GlobalClass.GlobalVariables.User.ID)
                {
                    DeleteAlbums.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (DeleteAccess != null)
                    {
                        DeleteAccess.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                Imagebutton.PostBackUrl = "../SitePages/AlbumView.aspx?aid=" + album.ID;
                EditAlbum.NavigateUrl = "../SitePages/AlbumView.aspx?aid=" + album.ID;
                sHyperLink.Text = string.Format("Share Album ({0})", album.AccessCount);
                sharecounter.Value = album.AccessCount.ToString();
            }
        }

    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>


<div id="divFullControlAlbums">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="FullAlbumCounter" />
    <h2>Full control albums:</h2>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ListViewPanel1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListViewPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>

        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" MinDisplayTime="0" />
    <asp:Panel ID="ListViewPanel1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadListView ID="lvFullControlAlbums" AllowPaging="true" runat="server" GroupItemCount="5" OnItemDataBound="AlbumSetup">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td3" runat="server">
                            <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td4" runat="server" style="">
                            <telerik:RadDataPager ID="RadDataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvFullControlAlbums"
                                PageSize="10">
                                <Fields>

                                    <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric" />

                                    <telerik:RadDataPagerTemplatePageField>
                                        <PagerTemplate>
                                            <div style="float: right">
                                                <b>Items
                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CurrentPageLabel" Text="<%# Container.Owner.StartRowIndex+1%>" />
                                                    to
                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TotalPagesLabel" Text="<%# Container.Owner.TotalRowCount > (Container.Owner.StartRowIndex+Container.Owner.PageSize) ? Container.Owner.StartRowIndex+Container.Owner.PageSize : Container.Owner.TotalRowCount %>" />
                                                    of
                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TotalItemsLabel" Text="<%# Container.Owner.TotalRowCount%>" />
                                                    <br />
                                                </b>
                                            </div>
                                        </PagerTemplate>
                                    </telerik:RadDataPagerTemplatePageField>
                                </Fields>
                            </telerik:RadDataPager>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>No data was returned.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <EmptyItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td1" runat="server" />
            </EmptyItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; margin: 0.7em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ShareCounter" />
                    <div id="HypeShareAlbum" style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<%#Eval("ID") %>" />
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypShareAlbum"></asp:HyperLink>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<%#Eval("CreatorID") %>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="EditAlbumClass">
                        <asp:ImageButton ToolTip='<%#Eval("AlbumDescription") %>' runat="server" ID="AlbumImage" Width="110"
                            Height="110" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("AlbumDefaultImageUrl") %>' />
                    </div>
                    <img src="../SiteImages/private.png" style="margin: 0" />
                    <span style="margin: 0">photos:
                            <%#Eval("PhotoCount")%></span><br />
                    <div id="hypDeleteAccess" style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<%#Eval("ID") %>" />
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypeDeleteAlbum" Visible="false" Text="Delete Album"></asp:HyperLink>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypeDeleteMyAccess" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Remove my Access"></asp:HyperLink>

                    </div>
                    <div class="EditAlbumClass">
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="EditAlbum" ToolTip='<%#Eval("AlbumDescription") %>' Font-Underline="false">
                            <p class="titleAlbums" runat="server" id="pTitle">
                                <%#Eval("AlbumName") %>
                            </p>
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
        </telerik:RadListView>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to include you script code as it is very often the cause of this problem, but without it, it is much more difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RadCodeBlock` or a `RadScriptBlock` around the offending code.